vega-lite deneb format chart legend with calculation group __formatted
with deneb visual in power bi we have



placeholder CG Продажи RWA RW
placeholder CG Продажи RWA RW__format
placeholder CG Продажи RWA RW__formatted




95430453917.96
#,##0,,.M
95,430m


50776655105
#,##0,,.M
50,777m


50433
#,##0
50,433


1.8794
#,##0.00
1.88



and we can add mark like this
and it's rendering perfect
     "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "dx": 30
      },
      "encoding": {
        "text": {
          "field": "placeholder CG Продажи RWA RW__formatted"
        }

but how can we use the same field with legend?

big thanks to dm-p (Daniel Marsh-Patrick)
https://github.com/deneb-viz/deneb/issues/517

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
